# Insert .NET server control to a DIV with Html Agility Pack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack, server-side

I selected a DIVlike this:

```
var divEl = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='" + field.Id + "']");
```

This DIV is empty.  Now I need to add a .NET TextBox server control to this DIV and then send the DIV back to the client.  How?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create an element representing the textbox, add the textbox as a child to the div and save the document to whatever stream you have open to the client.

```
var xpath = String.Format("//div[@id='{0}']", field.Id);
var div = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(xpath);
if (div != null)
{
    var textBox = HtmlNode.CreateNode("<asp:TextBox runat='server' />");
    div.AppendChild(textBox);
}

doc.Save(stream);
```

Comment: If you actually want to send just the div, use `div.WriteTo()` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,
i guess that will work, but the work I've been assigned is to "convert" fragment of a really big code-behind engine that generates table's, tr's and td's and web controls inside them to div's. I load this new div structure to a string from a DB field, that was previously inserted by a user, then I use html agility pack, to get this structure. Some div's have an ID and on this ID i need to insert a specific web control (ex: textbox and its validator). Do I need find a way to convert the web control html first to use '<asp:TextBox runat='server' />' ?